# How to update grub file from ubuntu bootable stick in order to disable flawed graphics card kernel

Tags: ubuntu, grub, nvidia, graphics

I have updated latest official nvidia drivers for my GT525M on Dell Vostro 3750. After quick prompt to update my kernel it succeeded and my system will not boot anymore. I reinstalled the system and after succesful installation problem persisted.

So I am trying to disable temporarily my graphics drivers in grub to only boot my system.
I have found this beautiful article:

https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/linux-cp-command/

Is there a way to update grub file from bootable stick?
I am not able to change the permision through file manager.

Any help apppreciated.

Comment: If you can boot to a terminal you can run your fixes from that. If UEFI press escape key between UEFI & normal time it shows grub to get menu to show. Or if old BIOS, press & hold shift key. Then boot using recovery mode which gives you options on repairing system. You may need network. How did you install nvidia driver. You should only install from Ubuntu repository. And have to purge if changing driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver

Comment: I can boot to termial only from usb stick. It seems it changed something in the kernel..

Comment: Graphic drivers are integrated into the kernel image. Can you boot older kernel? Did you install with Safe Boot and include proprietary drivers to get correct nVidia driver installed? Just to see configuration. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/